# Exception Message -> Array to string conversion" Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lucid

I am using Laravel lucid framework and I have to call model `setAttribute` explicitly but getting below error:

> ErrorException: Array to string conversion in

Code is

```
$user = new User;
$user->setAttribute('email',$this->email);
print_r($user);exit();
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What does `dd($this->email)` output?

Comment: it is simple email address, a string like (test@test.com)

Comment: Which of these lines throws that error? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use implode() method ? :**

```
$test = implode('', $array);

$user = new User;
$user->setAttribute('email', $test);
print_r($user);
exit();
```